# How to transform an hexadecimal value into a bit position [BitMapping] in C#?

Tags: c#, bitmap, hex, byte

My problem is:

I have an array, more precisely a `dictionary<int,string>` where the KEY INT is a hexadecimal value and the string is the meaning of that bit. Eg.:

```
Key,    Value
1       Cat
2       Dog
4       Ant
8       
10
20
40
80      Whale
...
```

I need to translate the hexadecimals values into the **BIT POSITION**. That is:

```
Bit
1      Cat
2      Dog
3      Ant
8      Whale
```

How can I do that in C# ?

Thank  you all.

Comment: What have you tried?  Show your code.  Is there a specific problem?  This is not a free programming service.

Comment: My problem is we are not your free programming service.  Show us what you have tried.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure exactly what you're going for, but have you considered using an [enum](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sbbt4032.aspx)?

```
enum MyEnum
{
    Cat = 1,
    Dog = 2,
    Ant = 4,
    Whale = 8
};
```

If you have a hex string, convert it to an int, and then you can figure out which bits are on or off.

Convert to string:

```
string hexString = "80";
int hexInt = Convert.ToInt32(hexString, 16);
```

Check nth bit:

```
// Let's say you want to see if the 8th bit is on.
if (((1 << 7) & hexInt) > 0)
{
    // our 8th bit is on
}
else
{
    // our 8th bit is off
}
```

I would recommend making a method to check the nth bit like so:

```
public bool checkBit(int bitPosition, int value)
{
    // returns true if bit is on, else false
    return (((1 << bitPosition) & value) > 0);
}
```

Note that the first bit position is 0. So whatever bit position you want to check, subtract 1.

Again, still not exactly sure what you're going for, but if you want to get a hex value for nth bit. You could do something like this:

```
// remember that the first bit position will be 0.
public string getHexStringForBitPosition(int bitPosition)
{
     // we can't go higher than 64.
     if (bitPosition > 63)
         return "0";
     ulong myVal = 1 << bitPosition;
     return myVal.ToString("X");
}
```

Comment: Ok, maybe I was not clear enough.
The hexadecimal "80" in binary is "1000 0000". That is, the 8th bit.

I don't know how to translate a hexadecimal that represents an specific BIT POSITION, into its decimal position

in that case, "80" in binary is "1000 0000" so its the 8th bit. 
How can I do that ?

Comment: If you want to check a specific bit position for a value, I updated my answer.